# How to copy an object structure without the property values?

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates

I have found myself needing to copy the structure of an object without any values.

For example:

```js
var foo = {
  name: 'Leo',
  address: '1234 Road'
}

var bar = someFunction(foo);

// bar now should equal:
// {
//   name: undefined,
//   address: undefined
// }
```

I do realize I can loop through the object keys and assign to the result, was just hoping there might be a simpler method.

Note: I chose the answer I did because it is the one I decided to use, but all the answers were excellent.

Comment: *"I can look through the object keys and assign to the result"*: that's indeed what you need to do. You can use recursion if your object is nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get properties of original object first. Secondly  you can use for example [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new object with the expected keys and values.

This can work for you:

```js
const foo = {
  name: 'Leo',
  address: '1234 Road'
};

const result = Object.keys(foo).reduce((a,c) => {
  a[c] = undefined;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your object is simple (no nesting), then you can use `Object.keys` to retrieve the keys, `.map` to create arrays of each of those, and `Object.fromEntries` to create the final result:

```js
const structure = o => Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(o).map(k=>[k]));

var foo = {
  name: 'Leo',
  address: '1234 Road'
}

var bar = structure(foo);

console.log(bar);
```

`Object.fromEntries` expects an array of pairs, but since we provide an array of single-element arrays, the second value in each pair is missing (i.e. is `undefined`) and so it will produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested objects then you can use a simple recursive algorithm to set any value that's not an object to `undefined` and then recursively apply the same transformation to any nested objects:

```js
var foo = {
  name: 'Leo',
  address: '1234 Road',
  department: {
    name: "accounting",
    location: "third floor"
  },
  favouriteFood: ["pancakes", "fish"]
};

var bar = someFunction(foo);

console.log(bar);

function someFunction(input) {
  //return `undefined` for primitives and arrays
  if (typeof input !== "object" || Array.isArray(input))
    return undefined;
  
  //otherwise go over all the entries of the object
  return Object.entries(input)
    //and make a new object
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      //recursively call `someFunction` to handle the value
      var newValue = someFunction(value);
      
      return {
        ...acc, //copy the object  
        [key]: newValue //add the current key-(mapped)value pair
      };
    }, {})
}
```

This can be shortened to the following:

```js
var foo = { name: 'Leo', address: '1234 Road', department: { name: "accounting", location: "third floor" }, favouriteFood: ["pancakes", "fish"]};

var bar = someFunction(foo);

console.log(bar);

function someFunction(input) {
  if (typeof input !== "object" || Array.isArray(input))
    return undefined;
    
  return Object.entries(input)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: someFunction(value)}), {});
}
```

And here is the implementation using a `for..of` loop instead of `Array#reduce`:

```js
var foo = { name: 'Leo', address: '1234 Road', department: { name: "accounting", location: "third floor" }, favouriteFood: ["pancakes", "fish"]};

var bar = someFunction(foo);

console.log(bar);

function someFunction(input) {
  if (typeof input !== "object" || Array.isArray(input))
    return undefined;
  
  const obj = {};
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    obj[key] = someFunction(value);
  }
  
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()`

```js
var foo = {
  name: 'Leo',
  address: '1234 Road'
}

let newFoo = {}

for (let key of Object.keys(foo)) {
    newFoo[key] = undefined    
}

console.log(newFoo)
```